# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (310:2392:17)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using MVC and using jQuery AJAX I called a action method the data I received from the action method is correct and when I use $("#id").val() it is showing the data correctly in the form of json but it is throwing error in console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at GetExistingSubList (310:2611:34)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (310:2392:17)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232:31)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362:7)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582:13)
    at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617:10)
```

Due to this error some of the JS functions aren't working

This is my controller code

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Getsubscriptiondata()
        {
            var subdata = db.ExistingSubscriptionList.Where(substatus => substatus.OSCP_SubStatusId == "1").ToList();

            return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subdata));
        }
```

This is my JS function with AJAX call

```
function getExistingSubValue() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",

            url: "/UserManagement/Getsubscriptiondata",
            contentType: false,
            data: {
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                
                $("#hdnExistingSubs").val(data);
                
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the JS code where I am using the data by parsing it

```
if (ServiceId != '' && CloudId == '1' && IdentityTenantId != '') {
                var flag = 0;
                var data = $('#hdnExistingSubs').val();

                var items = JSON.parse(data);

                var table = $('#tblExistingSubs').DataTable();
                table.rows().remove().draw();

                var result = [];
                for (var item, i = 0; item = items[i++];) {
                    result.push(item);
                }
```

Image of the Error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvYIs.jpg)

I have tried parsing the data after AJAX success call even it is throwing same error

Comment: @freedomn-m in the network tab the status code is 200 and the response has the data sent from the action method and I checked the type/ value of the data it is string.

Comment: Looking closer: `Unexpected end of JSON` indicates the JSON is incomplete.  Can you copy the string from the network tab into a json linter?  eg: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @freedomn-m when I copied the the string from network tab (response) and checked it in jsonlint.com after validating the data the results shows valid JSON

Comment: Ok, so assuming you are setting hcnExistingSubs.val correctly, exactly what is the value of `data` after `var data = $('#hdnExistingSubs').val();`?    A complete snippet (with the ajax simulated) that *demonstrates* the issue with some sample json would go a long way to remove guess work.  See [mcve].

Comment: The value of data after var data = $('#hdnExistingSubs').val() is string.
I have attatched the code for controller, JS, AJAX call, and function where the data is used. 

The data is in this format [{ "subid": "456-12","subname":"name","status":"active","OSCP_SubStatusId":"1","OSCP_CloudId":1}, "subid": "456-12","subname":"name","status":"active","OSCP_SubStatusId":"1","OSCP_CloudId":1}] 
this is example of how the data format in the network tab(response)

Comment: Probably just a typo in your comment, but your comment json is not valid json - missing `{`

Comment: yeah its a typo I just replicated the original data as example
this is the correct data  [{ "subid": "456-12","subname":"name","status":"active","OSCP_SubStatusId":"1","OSCP_CloudId":1}, {"subid": "456-12","subname":"name","status":"active","OSCP_SubStatusId":"1","OSCP_CloudId":1}]

Comment: The data is correct it is valid JSON but i am facing the error as uncaught syntax error JSON.parse